# No Network Devices Found Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

I Don't Know Why There's No Network

My Home have about 5 wifi

Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is currently in pre-release testing. It is off-topic here.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Ubuntu *hirsute* is in *feature freeze* currently and in the *bug hunting and fixing* stage currently... this is not an appropriate site for such things.. they belong on launchpad so others can confirm the issue & the bug has a chance of being fixed prior to release as Ubuntu 21.04 (it's *hirsute* until that time).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you solution is ifdown (name of you network interface) and ifup (name of interface) if you jus try this, so